# Popover for button created via code for long press

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter-bootstrap, uibutton

I know how to create popovers if my button added to story board, but how can I create popover if my button created via code.

```
UIButtonS *button = [UIButtonS buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];            
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(siteButtonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:string1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(XLocatioan, YLocation, 90, 30);

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                   initWithTarget:self
                                                   action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
[button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];    
[self.view addSubview:button];

-  (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
      //create popover for button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing it right, but you are overthinking. There is no need to check the state of the `gesture recognizer`. If the target function has been triggered, it means that the user has done a long press. Also, note that not all of the values of the property [state](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/state) may be supported. As the documentation says: `Some of these states are not applicable to discrete gestures`.

So your code should look like this (unless you want to implement dragging or something similar):

```
UIButtonS *button = [UIButtonS buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];            
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(siteButtonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:string1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(XLocatioan, YLocation, 90, 30);

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                   initWithTarget:self
                                                   action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
[button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];    
[self.view addSubview:button];

-  (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    //create popover for button        
}
```

If your target is `iOS 6+` you should use a [UIPopoverController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial) to create the popover, otherwise use [UIAlertView](http://hayageek.com/uialertview-example-ios/).